# Xamarin.Android vs. UrhoSharp camera node rotation based on Android device orientation

Tags: android, xamarin, camera, rotation, urhosharp

In my **Xamarin.Android** application I have orientation data for X, Y, Z axes got from device's **geomagnetic rotation vector** composite sensor and processed with [SensorManager.GetOrientation( )](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.SensorManager.GetOrientation/p/System.Single%5B%5D/System.Single%5B%5D/) method. I want to apply this orientation data in [UrhoSharp](https://github.com/xamarin/urho/blob/master/README.md)'s scene on the [Rotation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Urho.Node.Rotation/) property of CameraNode.
In other words I want to control the scene's camera using the device "orientation" sensors.

What I did so far in the [SensorChanged](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.ISensorEventListener.OnSensorChanged/p/Android.Hardware.SensorEvent/) event handler:

```
// app -> an instance of Urho.SimpleApplication
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.GeomagneticRotationVector) {
        var rm = new float[9];
        SensorManager.GetRotationMatrixFromVector(rm, e.Values.ToArray());
        var ov = new float[3];
        SensorManager.GetOrientation(rm, ov);
        app.Pitch = (Urho.MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(ov[0]) + 360) % 360;      // map [-Pi...+Pi] to [0...360]
        app.Yaw = (Urho.MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(ov[1]) + 360) % 360;        // map [-Pi/2...+Pi/2] to [0...360]
        app.CameraNode.Rotation = new Urho.Quaternion(app.Pitch, app.Yaw, 0);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it does not work as expected and camera looks always to wrong direction. Any idea?

========================================================

Update:

The best solution is to use rotation matrices with orientation sensor and to keep OnSensorChanged method as short as possible!

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// a global array
private float[] SensorData = null;

public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent? e) {
    SensorData = e.Values.ToArray();
}

// a task defined somewhere in the OnCreate async method
await Task.Run(async () => {
    var RM = new float[9];
    var outR = new float[9];
    var res = new float[3];
    var Azimuth = 0.0f;
    var Pitch = 0.0f;
    var Roll = 0.0f;

    while (true) {
        if (SensorData == null) return;

        SensorManager.GetRotationMatrixFromVector(RM, SensorData);
        var remap = SensorManager.RemapCoordinateSystem(RM, Android.Hardware.Axis.X, Android.Hardware.Axis.Z, outR);
        if (!remap) return;

        _ = SensorManager.GetOrientation(outR, res);
        Azimuth = (MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(res[0]) + 360.0f) % 360.0f;  // azimuth
        Pitch = MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(res[1]);                        // altitude
        Roll = MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(-res[2]);

        try {
            // finally update our Camera Node's Rotation property 
            cn.Rotation = new Quaternion(Pitch, Azimuth, Roll);
        }
        catch {
            // On [Urho.Application.Stop] this exception occurs.
            // Break is also required to exit from while loop!
            break;
        }

        RunOnUiThread(() => {
            // update our TextViews
            tvAzm.Text = $"Azimuth: {Azimuth,7:F2}";
            tvPitch.Text = $"Pitch:   {Pitch,7:F2}";
            tvRoll.Text = $"Roll:    {Roll,7:F2}";
        });

        // let's wait to avoid to frequent RunOnUiThread calls
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it with some research and help of @joe

Here is the final version of method:

```
// [app] is an instance of Urho.SimpleApplication
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.GeomagneticRotationVector) {
        var inR = new float[9];
        SensorManager.GetRotationMatrixFromVector(inR, e.Values.ToArray());
        var outR = new float[9];
        // we need to remap cooridante system, since the Y and Z axes will be swapped, when we pick up the device 
        if (SensorManager.RemapCoordinateSystem(inR, Android.Hardware.Axis.X, Android.Hardware.Axis.Z, outR)) {
            var ov = new float[3];
            SensorManager.GetOrientation(outR, ov);
            try {
                app.Pitch = (MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(ov[1]) + 360) % 360;
                app.Yaw = (MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(ov[0]) + 360) % 360;
                app.CameraNode.Rotation = new Quaternion(app.Pitch, app.Yaw, 0);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) {
                // while Urho.SimpleApplication is not fully started, the [app] properties are not available
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `OnSensorChanged` should be this:

```
   if (e.Sensor == mRotationSensor)
    {
        var rm = new float[9];
        SensorManager.GetRotationMatrixFromVector(rm, e.Values.ToArray());
        var ov = new float[3];
        SensorManager.GetOrientation(rm, ov);
        app.pitch = (Urho.MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(ov[1]) + 360) % 360;      // map [-Pi...+Pi] to [0...360]
        app.yaw = (Urho.MathHelper.RadiansToDegrees(ov[0]) + 360) % 360;
        Log.Error("pitch=",app.pitch+"");
        Log.Error("yaw=", app.yaw + "");
        // map [-Pi/2...+Pi/2] to [0...360]
        app.cameraNode.Rotation = new Urho.Quaternion(app.pitch, app.yaw, 0);

    }
```

And you need add these for your `SensorManager` in the `OnCreate` method:

```
 mSensorManager = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(Activity.SensorService);
 mRotationSensor = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.RotationVector);
 mSensorManager.RegisterListener(this, mRotationSensor, SensorDelay.Game);
```

And add the variables:

```
 private SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private Sensor mRotationSensor;
```

Finally don't forget implement `ISensorEventListener` interface for you Activity.

I have provided a demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/UrhoSharpFirstTest)

Comment: Hello @joe-lv-msft


Modified my OnSensorChanged based on your example but still not really OK.
What I want to reach is a similar functionality like in the [SkyView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.t11.skyviewfree) app. Basically I want to write my own planetarium application with live sky view.

Comment: Have you run my demo? Can it run on your phone? I will see SkyView

Comment: @joe-lv-msft

Going to try it. will let you know.

Btw Android SDK also provides method [SensorManager.GetQuaternionFromVector( )](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.SensorManager.GetQuaternionFromVector/)
Maybe it is better for this scenario. Or?

Comment: Why can't I find the app on my Google play store?

Comment: No Idea but there are many other similar application, for example [StarChart](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.escapistgames.starchart).

Can we chat on PM? U can reach me via [Messenger](https://www.facebook.com/heller.ladislav)

or [Hangouts](ladislav.heller@gmail.com)

BTW I tried your app, it does not handle the case when there is no *SensorType.RotationVector* sensor on device.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using quaternions:

```
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
    if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.GeomagneticRotationVector) {
        var qv = new float[4];
        SensorManager.GetQuaternionFromVector(qv, e.Values.ToArray());
        try {
            app.CameraNode.Rotation = new Quaternion(qv[1], -qv[3], qv[2], qv[0]);
            app.CameraNode.Pitch(90.0f);
            app.CameraNode.Roll(180.0f);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```